# svg images are not inserted in pdf while generating a pdf from html using itex7 html2pdf plugin

Tags: itext7, html2pdf, html-to-pdf

I am generating a pdf from multiple htmls. if any of the html consists **img** tag which refers to svg file like **`<img src="assets/6.svg" />`** then in generated pdf doesnt have image included. If I keep jpg or png, then its included as part of generated pdf. Its happening only if I use below code but if I use **`HtmlConverter.convertToPdf()`** then svg files are showing fine in generated pdf.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new File(pdfFileName)));
         pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
         Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
         document.setMargins(40, 40, 40, 40);
         for (String html : htmlFileList) {
                List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(html), converterProperties);
                System.out.println(elements.size());
                for (IElement element : elements) {
                    System.out.println(element.getClass().getName());
                    document.add((IBlockElement)element);
                }
              
         }
         document.close();
```

I am seeing error like below when generating a pdf from html using above code.

> Unable to retrieve image with given base URI
> (file:/C:/Projects/pdf_conversion/download/) and
> image source path
> (file:/C:/Projects/pdf_conversion/download/assets/cpc/img/icons/x_dont_gray.svg)

I am using above code because page content should be flown from page to page (dont want to create one pdf for one html). Any workaround is highly appreciated on this.